# finding nearest locations (longitude and latitude) using jquery

Tags: jquery, geospatial, latitude-longitude

I have a list of clinics which is fetched and cached in the clientside.
The list of clinic contains

- longitude
- latitude
- clinicname

I need to find the nearest clinic locations using jquery. Since I m working on jquery mobile, the client requirement explictly states that I need to work on the cached data rather than querying to the database.

Is there any way to implement **Geo-proximity search with jquery**?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it would help to know, how many entries this cached list contains? Is it acceptable to iterate through the whole list?

Comment: the cachelist won't be containing too many items..500 maximum

Comment: Are they spread over the whole globe (in which case you need to compute great-circle distances) or a relatively small area not too close to the N or S poles, in which case you can get by with a simple Euclidean distance (sqrt(dx^2+dy^2) with a latitude correction? How exact do you need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just made this for you. Hope it is what you are looking for.

It request for the person's location and gets the distance from him to a point (wherever the clinics are) (the first 4 functions). Then, it gets which one is has the shortest distance (the `shortestDistance` function).

```
var lat1 = "me"; //enter "me" to request location
var lon1 = 0;

var lat2 = NUMBERSHERE; //target's latency
var lon2 = NUMBERSHERE; //target's longitude
var name2 = "a";

var lat3 = NUMBERSHERE; //target's latency
var lon3 = NUMBERSHERE; //target's longitude
var name3 = "b";

var places = 2;

getDistance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2,name2);
getDistance(lat1,lon1,lat3,lon3,name3);

function getDistance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2,name2){
        if (lat1 == "me"){
                getLocation(lat2,lon2,name2);
                latto = lat2;
        }else{
                getDistancefrom(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2,name2);
        }
}

function getLocation(lat2,lon2,name2){
        if (navigator.geolocation){
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getDistanceFromMe);
                function getDistanceFromMe(position){
                        x = position.coords.latitude;
                        y = position.coords.longitude;
                        getDistancefrom(x,y,lat2,lon2,name2);
                }
        }else{ //geolocation not supported
        }
}



function toRad(value){
        return value * Math.PI / 180;
}

function getDistancefrom(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2,name2){
        R = 6371; //earth radius in km
        dLat = toRad(lat2-lat1);
        dLon = toRad(lon2-lon1);
        lat1 = toRad(lat1);
        lat2 = toRad(lat2);

        a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.sin(dLon/2) *
Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
        c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        d = R * c; //distance from YOU or Lat1 & Lon1 to Lat2 & Lon2
        shortestDistance(name2,d)
}

i = 0;
rdistance = ""
function shortestDistance(name,distance){
                if (rdistance == '')
                        rdistance = distance;
                if (distance < rdistance){
                        rname = name;
                        rdistance = distance;
                }
                i++;
                if (i == places){
                        alert(rname); //nearest place
                }
}
```

Distance formula from one point to another is taken from a [Haversine](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) example which was done with Javascript.